# считать данные json не из файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Как считать данные json не из отдельного файла?

Сейчас у меня считываются данные из файла content.json с таким содержимым

```
    {
      "monthly": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "This is a JSON event",
          "startdate": "2017-11-22",
          "enddate": "2017-11-22",
          "starttime": "12:00",
          "endtime": "2:00",
          "color": "#FFB128",
          "url": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Я хочу чтобы данные получались прямо из этого кода. Делаю так, но ничего не получаю.

```
    $('#mycalendar').monthly({
                mode: 'event',
                //jsonUrl: 'content.json',

                data: {
      "monthly": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "This is a JSON event",
          "startdate": "2017-11-22",
          "enddate": "2017-11-22",
          "starttime": "12:00",
          "endtime": "2:00",
          "color": "#FFB128",
          "url": ""
        }
  ]
},


            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: может потому что надо не `data` указывать а `events` ?

Comment: Точно, спасибо!!

Comment: Если вопрос решен, то [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы забыли предоставить ссылку на плагин, которым пользуетесь, то предпложим это вот этот https://github.com/kthornbloom/Monthly/blob/master/js/monthly.js

Поскольку документация плагина похоже напрочь отсутствует, то следует читать исходники. Как видно метод `AddEvents` ищет данные в свойстве `events` переданных параметров, а не `data`, как написано у вас. Если это свойство не заполнено то загружает события по указанному URL.

```
    function addEvents(month, year) {
        if(options.events) {
            // Prefer local events if provided
            addEventsFromString(options.events, month, year);
        } else {
            var remoteUrl = options.dataType === "xml" ? options.xmlUrl : options.jsonUrl;
            if(remoteUrl) {
                .......
            }
        }
    }
```

название вызываемой функции `addEventsFromString` вроде намекает на то, что это должен быть json, но что-то по факту внутри ее нет ничего что указывало на это.